# Changing the opacity of an UIView binded to a ViewModel with MVVMCross is not working in my Xamarin iOS app

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm struggeling to get the follow code to work. I want to change the opacity of an UIView (ButtonAnswer) binded to a ViewModel. I've tried a lot but I can't get it to work:

The following line is working:

```
this.CreateBinding(ButtonAnswer).For(v => v.Hidden).To((AnswerViewModel vm) => vm.Selected).Apply();
```

But this one is not:

```
this.CreateBinding(ButtonAnswer).For(v => v.Opacity).To((AnswerViewModel vm) => vm.Selected).Apply();
```

vm.Selected is a bool.

I don't know how to fix that. I hope that somebody can help me or can share a little bit of code.

Thanks!

Comment: Opacity is not a boolean

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using `ValueConverter`.

For example ( I am assuming that the property `Opacity` is of type `int` ) :

```
public class OpacityValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, int>
{
    protected override int Convert(bool visible, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return visible ? 100 : 0;
    }
}
```

Binding code

```
this.CreateBinding(ButtonAnswer)
    .For(v => v.Opacity)
    .To((AnswerViewModel vm) => vm.Selected)
    .WithConversion(new OpacityValueConverter(), null)
    .Apply();
```

More information about value converters can be found at:
https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-converters